# Enable Or Disable TextBox On Checkbox Changed Event In The Same GridView Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having a GridView on a webpage.In this gridview i have one Textbox & one CheckBox.
If CheckBox is checked then TextBox Should be enable & if it is unchecked then TextBox should be disable using pure javascript.

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdBasicApproval" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="90%"
                    CssClass="mGrid" DataKeyNames="EmpId">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField Visible="true" HeaderText="Remark">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRemark" runat="server" Width="125px" TextMode="MultiLine" Style="resize: none"></asp:TextBox>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="7%">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHeader" runat="server" Text="All" onclick="CheckAll(this);"
                                    TextAlign="Left" />
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChild" runat="server" onclick="return Check_Click(this);" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
```

And my JavaScript Is as below :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        try {
                            $("input[type=checkbox][id*=chkChild]").click(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    alert("Checked");
                    $(this).closest("tr", "").find("input[type=TextBox][id*=txtRemark]").attr("disabled", true);
                                        }
                else {
                    alert("UnChecked");
                    $(this).closest("tr", "").find("input[type=TextBox][id*=txtRemark]").attr("disabled", true);

                }
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    });
```

Comment: helping you is not the problem. But the problem is how? you haven't posted your code so that we can help. We ain't going to write code for you.

Comment: remove onclick="return Check_Click(this);"  first

Comment: After removing onclick="return Check_Click(this);" Still it is not working.

Comment: attr("disabled", true), both are true set one to false on click event

Comment: Hi Cracker.It does not make the textbox either enable or disable.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the event with checkbox in RowDataBound and pass the textbox to javascript function. In javascript function you can enable disable textbox.

*Code behind*

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{    
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("checkBoxId");
        TextBox textBox = (TextBox )e.Row.FindControl("textBoxId");
        chkBox.Attribute.Add("onclick", "EnableDisable(this, '" + textBox.ClientID + "');" );
    }    
}
```

*Javascript*

```
function EnableDisable(chkbox, textBoxId)
{
   document.getElementById(textBoxId).disabled = !chkbox.checked;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like

> HTML

```
   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox" runat="server" />
```

> Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("input[type=text][id*=TextboxId]").attr("disabled", true);
     $("input[type=checkbox][id*=CheckBox]").click(function() {
     if (this.checked)
     $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=text][id*=TextboxId]").attr("disabled", false);
     else
     $(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=text][id*=TextboxId]").attr("disabled", true);
     });
});
```

Comment: you can try visaversa for both.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {try {$("input[type=checkbox][id*=chkChild]").click(function () {if (this.checked) {
$(this).closest("tr","").find("input[type=TextBox][id*=txtRemark]").attr("disabled", true);
}
                    else {
                        $(this).closest("tr", "").find("input[type=TextBox][id*=txtRemark]").attr("disabled", true);
                        //document.getElementById('txtRemark').disabled = false; //Enable True.

                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code which check the checkbox and disable/enable the textbox relative to it

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_Text1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk_Check" onclick="ChangeText();" />
 <script>
    function ChangeText() {
        var chkb = document.getElementById('<%= chk_Check.ClientID %>');
        if(chkb.checked)
           document.getElementById('<%= txt_Text1.ClientID %>').disabled = true;
        else
           document.getElementById('<%= txt_Text1.ClientID %>').disabled = false;
    }
 </script>
```