# Enable a DropDownList in a GridViewRow on CheckBox checked/unchecked of the same row(using any of c#,jquery,javascript)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with a CheckBox and a DropDownList as template field columns. I am trying to enable the row's DropDownList when the CheckBox of that row is checked.

This is my aspx:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GdvCPRetailerMap" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Size="Small" CssClass="grid" BackColor="White" BorderWidth="0px" CellPadding="4" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" SkinID="GVSalesManager" GridLines="none" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" PagerStyle-ForeColor="#0066cc" PagerStyle-CssClass="gvPagerCss" PagerStyle-Font-Underline="true" PagerStyle-Wrap="true" OnPageIndexChanging="GdvCPRetailerMap_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="GdvCPRetailerMap_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="S.No" DataField="S.No." SortExpression="SNo">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="2%" />
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="true" Width="2%"/>
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="3%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkRow_CheckedChanged"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Channel Partner-1" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCP1" Enabled="false" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCP1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Channel Partner-2" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCP2" Enabled="false" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCP2_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have tried doing this in my CheckBox OnCheckedChanged event:

```
protected void chkRow_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox ck1 = (CheckBox)sender;

    GridViewRow grow =(GridViewRow)ck1.NamingContainer;
    DropDownList ddlR = (DropDownList)grow.Cells[6].FindControl("ddlCP1");

    if (ck1.Checked == true)
        ddlR.Enabled = true;
    else
        ddlR.Enabled = false;
}
```

But nothing seems to happen with this code. The breakpoint doesn't even get hit.

Can some one guide me in the right direction on how to enable a DropDownList of a GridViewRow whose CheckBox is checked?And also if there is any jquery or javascript code to achieve the same output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all you may need to do is make sure the CheckBox causes a PostBack. You can do this by setting the property `AutoPostBack` to true.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" 
    OnCheckedChanged="chkRow_CheckedChanged"
    AutoPostBack="true" />
```

As the [documentation for AutoPostBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.autopostback(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the CheckBox state automatically posts back to the server when clicked.

Also:

> #### Property Value
>
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> true to automatically post the state of the CheckBox control to the server when it is clicked; otherwise, false. The default is false.

Afterwards, there is no need to do the FindControl call on a specific cell. You can just simply call that on the GridViewRow itself.

```
protected void chkRow_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox ck1 = (CheckBox)sender;

    GridViewRow grow =(GridViewRow)ck1.NamingContainer;
    DropDownList ddlR = (DropDownList)grow.FindControl("ddlCP1");

    if (ck1.Checked == true)
        ddlR.Enabled = true;
    else
        ddlR.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. However is there a better way to achieve the same using jquery/javscript?

Comment: Probably. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24506951/3711928).